# Split string on multiple delimiters (PHP)?

Tags: php, string, explode

I have a long string which should be seperated on multiple delimiters. The delimiters are in an array. **The delimiters are groups of words**. Is the some nice short version to do that? The result should be in an array in the end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use  preg_split function. It accepts regex as first argument and your regex can OR multiple expressions

Comment: Yeah, but my delimiters are words, like *this is a delimiter*. How would that look like?

Comment: Delimiters containing multiple words are fine. You should build regex from your array as 

`this is a delimiter|this is a another delimiter|this is a third delimiter`